# Expired accesstoken problem xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, aspnetboilerplate

We are using the zero-core version of boilerplate with the xamarin forms app attached.

We have noticed lately that in some cases when the accesstoken in the mobile app has been expired, multiple api calls will get a 401 response resulting in getting a new accesstoken using the refreshtoken.

This seems to happen mostly when two or more api methods are called in an InitializeAsync within a viewmodel. The AbpApiClient seems to set the Authorization header for all the api calls beforehand.

The first method determines that the AccessToken has expired and thus sets the AuthenticateResult.AccessToken with the new AccessToken that has been returned by the RefreshToken method. Because the Header.Authorization have already been set for the other methods,  the next method will do exactly the same (sending the expired AccessToken to the back end and so on)

We are testing with relocating the SemaphoreSlim from the HandleAuthorizedResponse to the SendAsync to make sure the first method gets the chance to determine that the AccessToken has been expired before the next method makes its way into the SendAsync. We are unsure if this is a valid solution as now the SendAsync is always available for only one method, independent from if the AccessToken has been expired yes or no.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
            try
            {
                var tokenManager = IocManager.Instance.IocContainer.Resolve<IAccessTokenManager>();
                if (tokenManager.IsUserLoggedIn)
                {
                    var accessToken = tokenManager.GetAccessToken();
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AuthorizationScheme, accessToken);
                }
                var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized &&
                    HasBearerAuthorizationHeader(request))
                {
                    return await HandleUnauthorizedResponse(request, response, cancellationToken);
                }

                return response;
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleUnauthorizedResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tokenManager = IocManager.Instance.IocContainer.Resolve<IAccessTokenManager>();

            if (tokenManager.IsRefreshTokenExpired)
            {
                await HandleSessionExpired(tokenManager);
            }
            else
            {
                response = await RefreshAccessTokenAndSendRequestAgain(request, cancellationToken, tokenManager);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think you need to save the user and password (I know its not a best practice but you'll need that) and check if you Refresh Token fails to create a method to log in the user in the background and obtain a new token

Comment: @hairon This is what aspnetboilerplate tries to avoid by implementing a refreshToken to get a new accessToken. Saving a password is not an option to us.

Comment: In the past, I tried to implement a refresh token in Xamarin.Forms and doesn't work the method always return 401, so my only option was to do a background login

Comment: @LaraBlokker Did find a solution to this. We currently have a similar implementation in our app, but it seems using `SemaphoreSlim` slows down the performance of the requests.